# Can't push or pull to/from docker registry on localhost

Tags: docker

Running docker `Server Version: 17.03.1-ce` on Arch linux. Running registy:v2 on localhost:

```
docker run --name registry -d -p 5000:5000 \
       -e "REGISTRY_STORAGE=s3" \
       -e "REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_REGION=region"\
       -e "REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_BUCKET=bucket"\
       -e "REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_ACCESSKEY=redacted"\
       -e "REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_SECRETKEY=redacted"\
       registry:2
```

Set daemon to use localhost:5000 as insecure registry:

```
Insecure Registries:
 localhost:5000
 127.0.0.0/8
```

but push still fails with:

```
Attempting next endpoint for push after error: Get 
https://localhost:5000/v2/: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS 
client
```

I also get this on amazon-linux ec2.
This works fine on Ubuntu 16.04 with out setting insecure-regsitries.
Help!
I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: I did. That's why localhost:5000 is in the list of insecure registries above.

Comment: What do `docker logs registry` show?

Answer (score 0):

It was user error. I ran the container without the aws key id so it couldn't read the bucket.